# MS Query passing decimal as a parameter in an OBDC query

Tags: excel, parameters

I have a Postgres database with a table `responses` (columns `response_value` {`numeric(7,0)`} & `question_number` {`numeric(6,2)`}).

I have used MS Query to populate a table given the question number (i.e. 38.11, 10.01, 12).

If I use a simple query with the number in the query every thing works fine..

[MS Query without parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Mvf.png)

However if I replace the 38.11 with [QNum] for a parameter values show in MS Query

[MS Query using parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkxNl.png)

but when I return the data to Excel I get nothing

[Excel query with parameter 38.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV81U.png)

however if I change the parameter value to 10.01 I get data

[Excel query with parameter value 10.01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paJjq.png)

It works also with all other integer question numbers..

And not with any of the sub-questions to question 38... 38.01 etc.

Only question 10 & 38 have sub questions
 after the comment re date interpretation I went and added some dummy records to the tables with bogus question #s. 
Then went and used them as well and included question 10 variants as 10.01 gave results.. and got results that are really strange. The attached shows the questions I used and Y/N if they returned data.. and I query I did to make sure that there were rows for each of the questions. 
[MS Query questions that worked and those that didn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoslS.png)

I AM EVEN MORE BEFUDDLED than before.

Comment: I guess the entered data is sent as string to Excel. Excel interprets 10.01 as date. As dates are stored in Excel interbally as number of days since 1900, you get a numeric result. 38.11 could not be unterpreted by Excel as date, so it's stored as text (string).

Comment: Good idea.. I hadn't thought of that BUT it does not seem to be the case and not it get even more weird..